# Array state is disappeared when array mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm getting books from NYT API, so `useEffect` is working good. After `useEffect`, state has an array with books, but nothing is shown when trying to map this array. What did I do wrong?

I tried to create `newArr` array and display from that, but it also didn't work.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import BookServer from "./book-server/book-server";
import Card from "./components/Card";

import "./App.css";

function App() {

  const[books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const bookServer = new BookServer();
    const arr = bookServer.getBooks();
    setBooks(arr);
  },[]);

  return (
   <div className="content_books">
      {books ? books.map(item => {
        return <Card title={item.title} description={item.description} />
      }) : console.log(null)}

   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**BookServer.js**

```
// import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function httpGet(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
      } else {
        let error = new Error(xhr.statusText);
        error.code = xhr.status;
        reject(error);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(new Error('Connection failed'));
    };

    xhr.send();
  })
}

class BookServer {
  config = {
    apiKey: 'hidden',
    url: 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json'
  };
  books = [];


  getFromApi = () => {
    httpGet(`${this.config.url}?api-key=${this.config.apiKey}`)
      .then(response => {
        response.results.map(item => {
          this.books.push(item);
        });
      })
      .catch(reject => {
        console.log(reject)
      });
  };

  getBooks = () => {
    this.getFromApi();
    return this.books;
  }
};

export default BookServer;
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function Card({title, description}) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src="https://s1.nyt.com/du/books/images/9780553897845.jpg" className="card-img-top" alt="Game of thrones" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{description}</p>
        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `newArr`.

```
const[books, setBooks] = useState([]);
```

is already specifying `books` in it. Use it to map over the items.

Also, if get books is an asynchronous call. You can do a ternary to render `null` when the array is empty. This will prevent the initial loop with empty values in your markup and providing more checks on something like `book.name` which results in `name` of undefined errors.

Like this

```
 books ? books.map(book => {}) : null;
```

Comment: In books state i have an array with books after useEffect worked. When I want to show books I get nothing. Why? Maybe I do bad in BookStore.js?

Comment: The way you can check if `bookstore.js` is a problem is by replacing it with a simple API call within your useEffect hook. If that code with my modifications suggested works then definitely that file needs to be seen. But that will be a different problem altogether to post here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return your element after mapping your array otherwise it will not render.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const[books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json?api-key=${your_api_key}`,{
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res=>setBooks(res.results))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
  },[]);

  return (
   <div className="content_books">
      {books.map((item, index) => <div
       key={index}
       className="card">
        <img src="https://s1.nyt.com/du/books/images/9780553897845.jpg" className="card-img-top" alt="Game of thrones" />
        <div className="card-body">
           <h5 className="card-title">{item.title}</h5>
           <p className="card-text">{item.description}</p>
           <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      )}

   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: check again dude it's working and i am fetching api by using `fetch` method.

Answer (score 0):

You must know how lambda functions works.
If you are using `{}` you have to use `return`, because this is block of code:

```
new Arr.map(item => {
    return (
        <div>{item}<div>
    );
}
```

But lambda functions without `{}` by default use return statement:

```
new Arr.map(item => (
        <div>{item}<div>
    );
```